# Странный пересчёт репутации при переносе вопроса

Tags: поддержка, репутация, перенос-вопросов

14 марта [вопрос о размере диалога](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4925/178988) с самоответом был перенесён с основного сайта на мету.

Полученная за него репутация была списана, но

- 20 баллов за ответ (+2 -0) были списаны сразу
- 8 баллов за вопрос (+3 -1) списаны только сегодня - т. е. через 4 дня

**Чем вызвана задержка пересчёта на 4 дня?**

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основании [ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278729/339911) на MSE:

Репутация за ответ при переносе вопроса пересчитывается мгновенно. За вопрос - с задержкой до 30 дней. Реальный пересчет происходит при удалении, возникшем из-за миграции. Ответы удаляются сразу в этом случае, а вопрос еще доступен некоторое время на исходном сайте.

Comment: Интересно. Но прошло не 30 дней, а 4. От чего время удаления зависит?

Comment: @Qwertiy может как-то связано с переходом на https?

Comment: Вот [тут](http://meta.superuser.com/a/9340/362161) в комментариях упоминается удаление через 3 дня после миграции. Но сам вопрос был задан более чем за 30 дней перед удалением.

Comment: А понял, наверное. Там возраст вопроса берётся, а не отсчёт от миграции.