# Шуточные вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено

В честь празднования 1-го апреля был задан вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647030/182771.

С формальной точки зрения, вопрос содержит описание проблемы и код для ее воспроизведения. Однако ничего общего с "хорошим" вопросом он не имеет. И вот почему:

1. Он вообще не несет пользы

   - Вопрос синтетический, автор итак знает на него ответ, как следствие вопрос не несет пользы для автора.
   - Реальная проблема вопроса (специфика работы ASI в JS) не локализована и (кто бы мог подумать) не раскрыта в ответах.
   - С учетом предыдущего пункта, для людей, пришедших из поиска этот вопрос лишен смысла.
2. Шуточность вопроса противоречит идеям ru.SO - **распространению знаний** в формате вопрос-ответ. Фактически, это всего лишь информационный шум, замаскированный под реальный вопрос.
3. Вопрос изначально "шуточный". Именно поэтому, он набрал +10. В тоже время высокий рейтинга автора и самого вопроса может быть истолкован новичками как "пример *допустимого вопроса*". В контексте борьбы за *качество вопросов* на ru.SO - это контрпродуктивно.

---

В свете всего вышесказанного, предлагаю вынести на обсуждение вопрос о допустимости подобных "шуточных" вопросов на ru.SO.

**UPD:** а вот еще несколько шуточных вопросов:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647023/182771
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647034/182771
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647191/182771
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647220/181472

Comment: Stack Overflow: шутки здесь неуместны: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2697/stack-overflow-шутки-здесь-неуместны

Comment: А как же вопрос про бояс бэтмена: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647023/Программирование-пояса-бэтмена и других?)))   первые шесть   http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2017-04-01%20is%3aquestion  на сколько я помню были заданы 1 апреля

Comment: там вроде не ASI, а то, что строка `-->` это комментарий

Comment: Еще в чате некоторые, в т.ч. я спрашивали на счет удаления вопросов.....но что-то не заладилось

Comment: @Grundy, возможно. Но у меня нет времени, на поддержание клоунады на ru.SO.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, добавил еще примеров.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я считаю, что в интернете и так с юмором порой перебор, такие вопросы здесь не нужны.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov а ещё Вы забыли о том, что здесь не принято писать приветствия.

Comment: @alexolut Благодарю за ваш комментарий! `здесь не принято`, не принято кем? неужели это запрещено здесь? Я на данном ресурсе не так давно, но напишу, что здесь принято на мой взгляд, принято хамить в комментариях, особенно к вопросам новичков. Здесь не принято минусуя оставлять комментарий, но неплохим кажется плюсануть подобные [вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647023/234502) и прокомментировать.. Я стараюсь быть доброжелательным, неужели я сделал что-то странное, что вас побудило написать такой комментарий?

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov [не принято сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/93/176217). Если Вы посчитали мой комментарий оскорбительным - то это совершенно зря. Не ставил себе такой цели. Ну и благодарить тут тоже не принято :)

Comment: @alexolut вы меня конечно не оскорбили, и об этом я не писал. Ссылку что вы дали, там довольно интересная тема, ответ с 37 плюсами содержит `Время в современном мире бесценно`, далее вспоминаем об этих темах на 1 апреля и понимаем, что это все несерьезно и дальше можно не читать. Иначе говоря это мнение определенного круга лиц, но не сообщества. Я привык стараться быть доброжелательным, здороваться и благодарить, редко встретишь кому это не нравится, поэтому и спросил. У вас лично принято иначе, но не стоит говорить за сообщество в целом.

Comment: @Alexandr Kazakov   нерекомендованность использования информационного шума (приветствий, благодарностей, прочего savoir-faire и ненужных цитат) обусловлено желанием минимизировать keyword pollution,  грозы поисковых систем. Сайт предназначен для поиска информации на нем, а не для общения, для общения отведен чат. Это правило УНИВЕРСАЛЬНО для всех stackexchange

Comment: Здравствуйте @Swift ! Вы написали удивительное! Посмотрите пожалуйста данную тему, вопросы что здесь обсуждались были на основном сайте и были там примерно неделю, возможно вам стоит обратить внимание на это. Мне ли вы про "информационный шум" пишите? Вы решили написать здесь, чтобы донести до меня то, что не стоит проявлять доброжелательность? Вы желаете это обсудить? `а не для общения` у вас приветствие считается общением. Я правила таким образом не нарушаю, то к чему вы привыкли и чему лично следуете, я не принимаю и следую другому.

Comment: @Alexandr Kazakov Да? Это там обсуждалось годами. А если говорить об SO, там это возведено в правила поведения: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior Никто не запрещает и не наказывает за это, но такие комментарии  могут бытьудалены а вопросы отредактированы, к тому же есть специальная защита от @thankyou@ спама.  Ну и русская версия: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Сомнительным делом мне кажется то за что вы @Swift здесь боритесь и пытаетесь мне доказать. Вы конечно пропустили мой комментарий вам относительно данной темы, не помню что вы " боролись" за закрытие тех вопросов, но мои комментарии вас привлекли, отвечу. 1). `от @thankyou@ спама` очевидно что это когда сообщение пользователя состоит исключительно из благодарности, мои сообщения вы можете посмотреть, я по делу пишу, а приветствие это лишь дополнение. 2). Мое предложение вам, если это важно для вас, займитесь поиском вопросов и удалением в них приветствий/благодарностей, или оставьте это все.

Answer (score 12):

Волевым решением модераторов сделано следующее:

1. Первоапрельские вопросы перенесены на Мету в метку [1-апреля](/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f), а оригиналы удалены.
2. На вопросы наложена историческая блокировка.
3. Из комментариев к вопросам удалены посторонние обсуждения.
4. Добавлено описание к метке [1-апреля](/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f).

Это позволит:

- сохранить эти забавные вопросы, ответы, комментарии;
- не создавать плохой пример на основном сайте;
- сохранить рейтинги, но не влиять на репутацию, не заморачиваясь с community-флагом.

---

Ждем ваши новые смешные вопросы через год.

Comment: Здравствуйте! `Из комментариев к вопросам удалены посторонние обсуждения.` удивительно, из данного [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5069/234502) удалены все мои комментарии. Я там высказал свою точку зрения о том, что не всем это кажется смешным и сделал это корректно, не нарушая правил сайта. Предлагаю вам объяснить  на каком основании мои комментарии попали в `посторонние обсуждения`, а например данный комментарий `Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что гладиолус.` оказался уместным и не был удален. Можно сделать это в чате, но ответ я хочу получить.

Comment: Уря, вопросы разрешили!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, ваши комментарии про то, как нам с вами праздновать 1 апреля уместны для обсуждения на Мете (прямо в этом вопросе, например), а не под одним из этих самых первоапрельских вопросов. Так же как оффтопик надо обсуждать на мете, а не под самим оффтопиком.

Comment: Эм... а как же подождать решения сообщества? Собственно я вопрос создавал как раз для **обсуждения**, а не волевого выпиливания.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Вы считаете, что обсуждения не достаточно было?

Comment: @alexolut, ну как бы только полтора дня прошло.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev варианты кончились, чего ждать-то еще.

Answer (score 6):

Эти вопросы с самого начала нужно было отмечать как «общие», потому что сайт у нас не про юмор. Нет, мы любим шутки. Но репутация даётся за знания.

Сейчас вижу два возможных варианта:

- Удалить вопросы.
- Отметить как общие и повесить историческую блокировку.

Comment: Разве репа откатится в случае исторической блокировки?

Comment: @alexolut блокировка на репутацию вообще не влияет. Отметка «общие» тоже не снимет уже полученную репу.

Comment: значит второй вариант - не вариант.

Comment: @alexolut, так она и в случае удаление вроде не откатится?

Comment: @Qwertiy с чего бы? Всегда удаление откатывало репу. [Обсуждали ведь недавно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4944/176217).

Comment: В вашем ответе не раскрыт вопрос о том, что делать с меткой [tag:1-апреля]. Было бы здорово, если бы вы добавили идеи по этому поводу (именно с метки началось обсуждение).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я удалю свой вопрос и мне не жалко репутации, которая с ним прилетела, только если будут удалены все другие вопросы, которые были с метками "1-апреля". Справедливости ради..

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я считаю, что после первого апреля данные вопросы следовало удалить, если не пользователями, то модераторами. И поставить на метку какую-то фичу, что её можно поставить только 1 апреля, и в другие дни вопросы с этой меткой автоматически удаляются

Comment: @Yuri функционал автоматического чего бы то ни было вряд ли будет (читай как - не будет никогда) реализован применительно к обсуждаемой теме.

Comment: @alexolut, перенос != удаление. Кажется.

Comment: @Qwertiy перенос приводит к удалению. Это есть в ответе по ссылке.

Answer (score 4):

Эти вопросы опубликованы **1 апреля**. Сообщество [изъявило мнение, что как-то его отпраздновать надо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4682/181100) (+19/-3) и сопротивления таким вопросам (шквала закрывашек) в этот день я не увидел. Так что предполагаю, что **они считались уместными в тот день**.

Но тот день прошёл. Теперь всё как обычно, такие вопросы неуместны и должны быть закрыты или удалены по обычным правилам.

---

Однако, **предлагаю на шуточные вопросы, заданные 1 апреля (когда они *были* уместны), повесить историческую блокировку**. Которая пояснит, что вопрос может быть интересен, но не обязательно является уместным для StackOverflow.

Далее, дабы предотвратить создание подобных вопросов в будущем (иначе чем 1 апреля), предлагаю для метки [1-апреля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f) добавить описание, в котором пояснить ситуацию:

> НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ. Для вопросов, приуроченных к празднованию дня смеха (1 апреля). Во все прочие дни действуют обычные правила, а "праздничные" вопросы блокируются.

Про подробное описание метки загадывать не стану, пока не принято решение здесь, краткое описание тоже черновик. Но их смогут отшлифовать и сами участники, никакого особого вмешательства сверху для этого не нужно.

Comment: Метку надо все–таки удалить. Представьте, завтра Microsoft решит провести конкурс и попросит метку для этого (допустим, мы согласились). По прошествию надо удалить специальную метку? Конечно! Но найдутся те, кто сошлется на прецедент с первым апреля. И будет прав. Либо у нас есть чистая база меток, описывающих технологии о которых идет речь на сайте, либо будет неразбериха.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky тут может быть техническая необходимость. Гляньте на вопрос про пояс Бэтмена, например. По-хорошему, из него необходимо выкинуть вообще все метки. Но без меток вопрос существовать не может. А ссылаться на "прецедент" не получится, если в описании метки будут прямо изложены "правила игры", которые запрещают постить по этой теме вопросы кроме как 1 апреля. Так что нет, не будет прав.

Comment: Кто запретит мне создать десяток таких меток и конкурсов? На новый год, день рождения каждого участника с репутацией больше 10К или по другому поводу? Чем первое апреля лучше других?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Мета.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky и нет, "чистая база" и "неразбериха" это не два дискретных состояния. Система меток разработана с целью функционировать на открытом сообществе, а потому небольшие отклонения от "идеальной эксплуатации" не оказывают существенного влияния на её работу. Скажем, есть вот метка [tag:соревнование]. Мешает она нам?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev закрыть != установить историческую блокировку. Закрыть нельзя из-за конкурса. Если мы примем решение, что такие вопросы подлежат закрытию/блокировке/удалению/ещё чему-то, модераторы могут привести это решение в исполнение. Отменив конкурсы на них, если необходимо.

Comment: @D-side деньги за конкурс вернут, если отменят? ))

Comment: «Соревнование» – это отличная метка, которая напрямую относится к фильтрации вопросов на сайте.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky **все** метки напрямую относятся к фильтрации вопросов на сайте, это следствие того, что они технически из себя представляют :) [tag:1-апреля] не исключение.

Comment: @D-side Здравствуйте! Позволю себе высказать мнения на ваше сообщение. `Сообщество изъявило мнение` ' это звучит внушительно, но вот только цифры `(+19/-3)` выдают. Сразу проблема становится очевидна - нет мин. порога проголосовавших. Например, человек старается обсуждать только важные вопросы, увидел заголовок той темы и решил даже не заходить(т.к. что там можно обсуждать), следовательно его голос не учтен. Очевидно, что нужен минимальный порог кол-ва проголосовавших, для принятия решения, иначе 22 человека будут являться "голосом" сообщества.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Мета открыта всем участникам, с очень небольшим порогом репутации, и чуть больше двух недель вопрос провисел с меткой [meta-tag:важное] ([пруф](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4682/revisions)), и показывался **всем**. Достаточно поводов считать, что все, кому было не наплевать, оставили свой голос. Времени было достаточно, освещения тоже. Голосов тоже относительно немало (посмотрите, сколько обычно их оставляют). Так что есть из чего делать выводы. **На мой взгляд**, 22 голоса для Меты это **много**.

Comment: Я не говорю про все темы, но обязательный порог проголосовавших для таких "несерьезных" тем. Сделать хотя бы 50 человек, сейчас только в одной данной [теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647023/234502) 332 просмотра, следовательно 50 человек не так и много от их числа. Если мин. порог не достигнут, следовательно это и не нужно никому. Сопоставляйте кол-во проголосовавших с потенциальным кол-вом просмотров. `больше двух недель вопрос провисел с меткой важное` мое мнение, что когда человек не заходит в тему с таким заголовком, в этом нет ничего странного.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov любой численный порог будет либо слишком высоким (если решение затрагивает небольшую часть сообщества), либо слишком низким (если большую). Формализовать это не получится, остаётся считать относительную статистику. И прилагать усилия к тому, чтобы заинтересованные стороны ознакомились. Что касается "человек не заходит в тему с таким заголовком" -- значит, его не волнует эта проблема и любое решение на Мете его устроит. Если результат не устраивает, то, кхм, сам виноват, доверился большинству активных участников.

Comment: Поскольку лично мне неизвестна логика работы счётчика просмотров (учитывает ли он одного участника по нескольку раз, учитываются ли незарегистрированные), это число для меня бесполезно.

Comment: `(шквала закрывашек) в этот день я не увидел. Так что предполагаю, что они считались уместными в тот день.` - всё банально просто. закрывашек не было, потому что все видели и знали к чему относятся эти вопросы и, возможно, предполагая, что после этого дня они уйдут в небытие и поэтому смысла закрывать нет... но не тут-то было)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский от меня закрывашек тоже не было. Но я не закрывал их по той причине, что часы показывали `1 АПР`, а что должно было произойти с ними далее, должно было решить сообщество. Так что не все :) А что делать, как раз здесь сейчас и решаем.

Comment: Удивительно, что здесь модератор @Nicolas Chabanovsky пишет. Казалось бы, еще перед тем, как создавать метки с такими названиями: `бэтмен` `пояс-бэтмена` `1-апреля` нужно было четко решить что с ними(и с сообщениями) в будущем делать, но судя по этой теме, ни пользователи, ни администрация еще даже не знают, что с этим будет. Видимо строгость правил работает не для всех. Предлагаю определить, какое наказание заслуживают модераторы допустившие это, которые позволили написать подобные метки и сообщения(с которыми не все согласны), даже не уведомив пользователей о их дальнейшей судьбе.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov [метки создаются **не обязательно модераторами**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), если что.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov [Метки может создавать любой участник достигший заданного порога репутации, _без чьего какого бы то ни было разрешения_](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). О дальнейшей судьбе метки сообщество решает «по факту».

Comment: Система меток, на мой вкус, на SO прекрасная для открытого сообщества. У неё есть "каноническое назначение", но стремление к нему обеспечивается не технически, а самими участниками исходя из самого назначения механизма меток (и некоторым сформировавшимся из этого "рекомендациям"), а не согласно каким-то отфонарным правилам (которые просто где-то написаны). И используя метки, нельзя устроить больший беспорядок, чем не используя их. И это прекрасно.

Comment: Я слегка идеализирую, разумеется. Но в аргумент, что метки якобы показывают допустимую тематику сайта, и это может сподвигнуть новых участников постить оффтопик на основе меток, я не верю по двум причинам: (а) приходят обычно с *вопросами*, а метки подбирают уже по ним, (б) капс в кратком описании привлекает внимание.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky у каждого модератора, логичная задача, осуществлять проверку и пресекать нарушения правил сообщества, если я вижу [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647023/234502) "Изменен вчера Nicolas Chabanovsky". Следовательно администрация в курсе и со всем согласна. Удивительно, сейчас 5 апреля и существует эта тема, а те вопросы и метки до сих пор висят. Предлагаю администрации дать скорый ответ, на вопрос, что с этим(метки и сообщения) будет в дальнейшем, или закрыть/удалить те темы. Затем решить кто во всем этом виноват.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov а с чего бы это ответ на этот вопрос должна давать **администрация**, если мешают или не мешают эти вопросы **пользователям**? Это скорее пользователей нужно спросить, что на StackExchange обычно и делают. Этим мы тут, собственно, и занимаемся.

Comment: Вижу как здесь порой жестко и безкомпромиссно закрываются/минусуются темы новичков, и вот вижу тему с меткой `пояс-бэтмена` которая висит уже не первый день, с позволения администрации, и уже создана данная тема в которой выясняется что далеко не все с этим согласны и никто даже не знает что с этим(сообщениями и метками) делать в дальнейшем. Предлагаю также жестко и безкомпромиссно наказать виновников(модераторов допустивших или пользователей создавших темы). Если этого не будет сделано, то это означает двойные стандарты и что правила не для всех. @D-side смотрите мои прежние комментарии.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, а вы знаете сколько всего меток на ruSO?

Comment: @avp Здравствуйте! Вы своим вопросом как-будто во флуд хотите тему увести. Если есть что про метки сказать, говорите прямо, или я могу к чату подключиться. Раз уже данный комментарий написал, отвечу, нет не знаю сколько меток, но если вы хотите меня убедить что метка `пояс-бэтмена` весьма полезна, лучше это попытаться сделать в чате.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky *Кто запретит мне создать десяток таких меток* так никто и не запрещает, но эта метка и вопросы появились не самовольно и стихийно, а после долгого (2 месяца) обсуждения на Мете. Кстати, аргумент, что, прикрываясь этими метками и 6-ю вопросами, люди начнут творить беспредел мне кажется, мягко говоря, надуманным.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36545855#36545855

Answer (score 4):

1 апреля прошло, данные вопросы не уместны на данном ресурсе, их нужно удалить.

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу ничего плохого в том, что один раз в году будут появляться подобные вопросы с упомянутой меткой [1-апреля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f). [Идея такой метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4737/176217) (правда, с чуть более расширенным функционалом) была поддержана сообществом. На текущий момент 7 "за", 1 "против".

Считаю подобный шаг дополнительным способом повышения пользовательской активности на ruSO. По аналогии со "шляпами", которые активируются в новогодние праздники. В этот сезон также можно наблюдать не совсем адекватное голосование за, казалось бы, простые вопросы.

Наличие метки [1-апреля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f) под вопросом чётко говорит о необычности вопроса. И по этому признаку его однозначно можно отделить от остальных. Точно так же как закрытые вопросы могут продолжать существовать на сайте, хотя их тоже можно было бы отнести к категории "шума" в таком случае.

Новичками вообще очень много всего может быть истолковано не так, как это видится в концепции сети Stack Exchange. Именно поэтому возможности сайта для участника расширяются постепенно, по мере увеличения его репутации. Проводить аналогию вида: участник с большой репутацией задал вопрос, набравший большой рейтинг - значит такие вопросы хороши, можно. Но на метки иметь смысл всё же обратить внимание. Так же как стоит обращать внимание на то, что вопрос может быть закрыт при достаточном кол-ве голосов "за". В эту категорию ещё можно добавить и вопросы со списком литературы.

А вот наличие меток типа [пояс-бэтмена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81-%d0%b1%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0) мне кажется действительно лишним.

Если всё же подобные вопросы не хочется оставлять на основном сайте, их можно перенести на Мету второго апреля.

Comment: Мне недавно к одному моему вопросу написали комментарий `Почитай правила составления вопросов.` **alexolut** перешел по ссылке из вашего сообщения, там один из комментариев `Делаем фейковые вопросы и ответы, а потом целый год выявляем дураков` в топе и набрал семь плюсов. После этого, любые правила здесь кажутся чьей-то шуткой. Здесь на мете немало тем типа "За что меня минусуют", люди пытаются добиться справедливости, а перейдя [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647023/234502) и видя рейтинг сообщения, становится понятно, какие сообщения здесь вызывают особый интерес и активное обсуждение.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov именно поэтому метку [tag:1-апреля] надо оставить под вопросом. Или удалить **вместе** с вопросом.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov про `Почитай правила составления вопросов` я Вас не понял.

Comment: @alexolut Никакая метка не подгонит вопрос под критерии, описанные в справке.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вопросы, не удовлетворяющие критериям из справки - закрываются, блокируются или удаляются. Но решается это исключительно сообществом, и в редких случаях - модераторами. Вы, как участник сообщества, можете проголосовать должным образом по соответствующим вопросам. Если наберётся достаточное кол-во голосов, согласных с Вами - Вы получите ожидаемый результат. Поэтому пока вопрос по мотивам первого апреля жив - под ним должна быть метка [tag:1-апреля], или подобная, для уменьшения неоднозначных интерпретаций.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, вариантов не так много. Давайте их и рассмотрим.

## Удалить или нет?

Вопросы интересные, они набрали довольно много плюсов. Удалять их нечестно.

И вообще, новостные сайты же фейковые новости не удаляют.

И [RFC для чайников](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTCPCP) вместе с 418м http-кодом никто не удалил.

## Оставлять ли метку [1-апреля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)?

Если вопросы остаются, то у них должен быть какой-то набор меток. У нас есть вопрос про пояс Бэтмена, у которого вообще ни одной тематической метки нет - на мой взгляд универсальная [1-апреля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f) куда полезнее, чем [бэтмен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd).

Напоминаю, что и закрытые вопросы, и вопросы с исторической блокировкой по-прежнему должны иметь метки. Не превращать же их в [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

К тому же, эти вопросы надо как-то отличать от других. Иначе вопросы могут начать получать минусы и/или странные ответы. Конечно, можно писать в самом вопросе какую-то фразу, но зачем городить огород ради изобретения того, что делают метки?

В описание метки вполне можно добавить, что она может использоваться один день в году.

## Закрывать ли вопросы?

Думаю, это неважно. Вопросов мало, желающих на них неожиданно ответить, вероятно, ещё меньше. Т. е. если не закрыть, то мешаться они всё равно не будут, а если закрыть... то тоже не будут.

Но во втором случае они должны как-то заметно отличаться от других. Возвращаемся к полезности метки.

## Ставить ли историческую блокировку?

С идейной точки зрения это имеет смысл. Но тогда вопросы исключаются из поиска, а они довольно новые и внешних ссылок на них мало. На мой взгляд, лучше уж оставить их с единственной меткой [1-апреля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f) - тогда они не будут мешаться в поиске по другим меткам, но их всё ещё можно будет искать и голосовать.

---

## А теперь по конкретному вопросу

> В честь празднования 1-го апреля был задан вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647030/182771.

> С формальной точки зрения, вопрос содержит описание проблемы и код для ее воспроизведения. Однако ничего общего с "хорошим" вопросом он не имеет.

Классический пример XY-проблемы про забивание гвоздей микроскопом тоже синтетический. Но это же не мешает ему служить примером того, как надо задавать вопросы.

Так же и этот вопрос хороший, поскольку в нём есть всё: минимальный воспроизводимый пример, желаемое поведение и описание проблемы.

> Вопрос синтетический, автор итак знает на него ответ, как следствие вопрос не несет пользы для автора.

Эм.. Знание ответа на вопрос автором не является критерием хорошего или плохого вопроса.

> Реальная проблема вопроса (специфика работы ASI в JS) не локализована и (кто бы мог подумать) не раскрыта в ответах.

Нет, автопостановка точки с запятой не является реальной причиной того поведения, так что вполне логично, что она не появляется в ответах.

В принятом ответе говорится о том, что браузер боится минусов в начале строки - и это как раз очень близко к истинной причине. В ES6 для браузером вводится, что сочетание `-->` в начале строки служит началом однострочного комментария.

> С учетом предыдущего пункта, для людей, пришедших из поиска этот вопрос лишен смысла.

Во-первых, что именно должны искать те, кто попадёт в этот вопрос?

Во-вторых, это повод покопать и узнать что-то новое.

> Шуточность вопроса противоречит идеям ru.SO - **распространению знаний** в формате вопрос-ответ. Фактически, это всего лишь информационный шум, замаскированный под реальный вопрос.

Почему RFC для чайников никто не удалил и большинство http-серверов знают status-text для кода 418? Или уровень шума на SO должен быть ниже чем в RFC?

> Вопрос изначально "шуточный". Именно поэтому, он набрал +10. В тоже время высокий рейтинга автора и самого вопроса может быть истолкован новичками как "пример *допустимого вопроса*". В контексте борьбы за *качество вопросов* на ru.SO - это контрпродуктивно.

Хм.. А если бы автор начал свой путь на SO с подобных вопросов, а потом, по мере своего роста, набрал бы такую репутацию?

И ещё раз: этот вопрос идеален с точки зрения формулироки проблемы. И он полностью удовлетворяет всем критериям SO. Что именно в этом вопросе может быть истолковано новичками неверно, я не вижу. Далее, если он останется помечен меткой [1-апреля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f), то вроде бы всем очевидно, что не 1 апреля шуточные вопросы/ответы будут не в тему.

Comment: TL;DR напрашивается!

Comment: Согласен. Оставить вопросы, метку и репу (по крайней мере за попытку повеселить(ся)).

Comment: @Qwertiy Здравствуйте! Очень интересный вы здесь анализ провели. Позволю себе спросить у вас, `Вопросы интересные, они набрали довольно много плюсов. Удалять их нечестно.` считаете ли вы что на данном ресурсе определенное количество плюсов, это гарант качества вопросов? Я конечно минус поставил этому вашему ответу.

Comment: `Вопросы интересные, они набрали довольно много плюсов. Удалять их нечестно.` - мне кажется их и плюсовали-то тоже по приколу))

Comment: Вот твой вопрос, как раз, я б лично оставил бы.....а вот бэтмента точно нет

Comment: Вы допускаете, что вопрос про пояс бэтмена вообще стоит оставлять. Метки нужны для определенной цели. Наличие метки [tag:1-апреля] на сайте для разработчиков противоречит этой цели – мы засоряем нашу базу меток. Что и логично: нет метки, не должно быть и вопроса – вопрос про пояс бэтмена следует удалить вне зависимости от решения по остальным. Высказывая идею оставить метку, часто ссылаются на обсуждение празднования 1го апреля на Мете. Легко допустить, что в будущем, кто–нибудь добавит еще одну не тематическую метку, ссылаясь на решение оставить [tag:1-апреля], и будет прав.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `а вот бэтмента точно нет` ... [бэтменоненавистники!](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%91%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: @alexolut, ты так говоришь [бэтменоненавистники](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%91%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) как будто это что-то плохое ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Перенести данные вопросы на Мету. Тем более, что есть прецеденты с переносом оффтопика на Мету.

Comment: Чем они лучше тут, чем там?

Comment: @Qwertiy отсутствием изменения репы. Хотя расширение онтопичности на Мете - это тоже увеличение шума. Желание охватить побольше аудитории на ruSO приводит к искажению миссии SE. Надо просто понять, что для всякого трепа надо идти на другие сайты с форумами, или в местный чат. Но поиск из гугла в чат SE меня ни разу не приводил, да и выделить там тему довольно проблематично, если не создать отдельный чат, который еще должны как-то найти желающие ответить.

Comment: @alexolut Замечу, что никакого желания «охватить больше аудитории» нет. Перенося часть не тематичных вопросов на Мету, мы лишь хотим дать возможность сообществу обсудить важные по мнению самого сообщества темы, которым не место на основном сайте.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky больше разрешённых тем - больше аудитория. Не важно, на Мете это будет или нет. enSO - о программировании, meta.enSO - о enSO. Всё, точка. А у нас на Мете - всякие [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе] уже протащились, например.

Comment: @alexolut Только дело в том, что никто не хочет расширять тему. «Диалоги–о–работе» – это явный пример того, что «желание» расширить тему на самом деле лишь желание. На практике, такие вопросы не вызывают живой интерес у участников Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky судя по голосам на этих вопросах - интерес вполне себе имеется. И не малый.

Comment: @alexolut В моем понимание, о проявление интереса можно судить по количеству и качеству вопросов и ответов. Если что–то нам действительно интересно, мы готовы тратить свое время. Чтобы голосовать, много сил не требуется.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky когда вопрос задан и удовлетворительный ответ получен - люди голосуют "за", а не пишут такие же вопросы и ответы, с которыми они согласны. Следующий показатель - кол-во просмотров, несмотря на то, что это ещё проще, чем голосовать. Всё это отражает интерес.

Answer (score 0):

В сети StackExchange есть прецедент, когда шуточные вопросы задаются со специальной меткой, детали описаны [в этом ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4737/224820).

На мой взгляд, в шести заданных вопросах нет ничего, что может навредить базе знаний ru.stackoverflow, шквал неадекватного поведения (которого так почему-то боятся) они не могут вызвать.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Конечно, сложно вам придерживаться другой позиции, когда вы автор одного из вопросов, а к другому дали ответ. Но позволю себе спросить у вас, `... они не могут вызвать` на чем основано столь уверенное заявление? На мой взгляд, возможно это предсказание будущего, или ответ получен путем глубокого исследования и анализа данного вопроса? Поставлю минус вам, т.к. в данный момент ваше заявление звучит неубедительно.

Answer (score -3):

Никому вопросы не мешают, оставить их в покое.

Answer (score -3):

Оставить вопросы и ответы в покое, но вычесть репутацию, полученную за них, т.к. она (репутация) является отражением вклада участника в сообщество и помощь по реальным проблемам.

Comment: Неплохой вариант, но интересно, как технически его предлагается осуществлять. Блокировка не обнулит голоса. Если сделать их общими, тоже не будет эффекта. Разве что откреплять от аккаунтов, с пересчётом, и закреплять исходное авторство в теле сообщения (а указывать авторство необходимо, т. к. CC-BY-SA).

Comment: Почему не будет эффекта, если сделать их общими?

Comment: Кхм, а разве старания по придумыванию интересной шутки не должны оплачиваться?

Comment: @Other, отдельно, в конверте - пожалуйста. Только при чём тут "вклад в сообщество"?

Comment: @vp_arth, репутация, полученная **до** превращения в общий остаётся.

Comment: @D-side честно не знаю... но ТАМ, наверху, могут всё, наверное

Comment: @Other простите, но [шутка про "очки или Джоули в репу"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=31765016#31765016) прямо напрашивается :Р

Comment: Перенести на Мету, как я предлодил в отдельном ответе. Авторство останется, репутация откатится.

Comment: @alexolut о, да, это вариант. Тем более что есть прецеденты с переносом оффтопика на Мету.

Comment: @D-side, ох уж эта любовь к злословию; ясна пихта что в очках к репутации. А специально для кроликов - в морковных noчатках.

Answer (score -13):

### Событие:

- Небольшая группа людей назвала себя целым "сообществом" и грубо нарушила правила ресурса, тем что пренебрегла правилами составления вопросов и проявила вседозволенность. На узкоспециализированном ресурсе с серьезными и важными темами, была попытка устроить потеху и игру.
- Некоторые из людей написавших данные вопросы, имеют высокую "репутацию" на сайте, казалось бы, они должны быть примером для других в своем поведении и в своих вопросах, но вместо этого, они стали примером, возможности проявления вседозволенности на сайте, подорвав доверие к правилам сообщества в целом.
- Все это стало возможно, только с попустительства администрации(модераторов) сайта, следовательно большая часть вины ложится на них.

### Предложение:

1. Как можно скорее удалить все эти вопросы, данный ресурс ценится из-за других вопросов-ответов, но точно не из-за подобных, сохранять их не стоит ни в каком виде.
2. Строго наказать всех виновников данного беспорядка, а именно:

   - В обязательном порядке наказать модераторов, проявивших халатность и допустивших такое поведение на сайте.
   - Пользователей создавших данные вопросы наказать, минимальное наказание пусть будет превращение всех плюсов за данные вопросы в минусы в "репутацию" им, но более подходящее наказание будет в виде кратковременного бана на сайте, за их поведение и нарушение правил по создания вопросов.

Comment: А я наказываю, жестоко наказываю (с)

Comment: А Вы модер чтобы назначать наказание приказом за нарушение, которое Вы считаете таковым?

Comment: В сторону новичков и рядовых пользователей работают наказания, а если здесь не работают, это означает двойные стандарты и что "правила" не для всех здесь. Не думайте что ваше мнение, это мнение всех людей, и не думайте если вам смешно, то смешно всем.

Comment: ТС, изучите правила, прежде чем бузить: сообщество открыто обсуждало этот вопрос, то, что Вы не высказались там - только Ваша проблема.

Comment: Вы сами не понимаете всю абсурдность вашего "предложения"? Предложение не может быть "в обязательном порядке" - это всего лишь предложение...

Comment: Ещё раз [напоминаю, что "Сайт создан и управляется *сообществом*."](/tour). Если вы не считаете сообществом посетителей Меты, интересно послушать ваши предложения о том, как сообщество (в вашем понимании) должно изъявлять свою волю. Вполне понятно, что администрация не станет приводить ваше предложение в исполнение просто потому, что вы так сказали.

Comment: @D-side я могу лишь повторить один из своих предыдущих комментариев вам `смотрите мои прежние комментарии`. Повторю, для подобных "шуточных" вопросов установить минимальный порог по количеству проголосовавших, если не наберется, следовательно никому это и не нужно.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov а вы, видимо, не читали [мой ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5048/%d0%a8%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b/5067?noredirect=1#comment18501_5052), который объясняет, почему такой порог ввести невозможно.

Comment: Кому эти излишние сложности нужны? Анализировать всех юзеров, активных, активных на мете, ранжировать по репутации, реализовать функционал по принятию решения с учётом всего вышесказанного и всё только из-за того, что одному мелкореповому юзеру что-то не нравится.

Comment: Не думайте `Other` что здесь все здесь согласны с вашим неуважительным отношением к собеседнику. Вы считаете нормой подобные слова`мелкореповому юзеру` `изучите правила, прежде чем бузить`. Мне лучше на данном ресурсе иметь невысокую репутацию, чем научиться изъясняться подобным образом. Если вдруг окажется, что я вас порой игнорирую, знайте, что это из-за вашего хамского поведения.

Comment: Ну-ну. У Вас мало репы, что говорит о малом знакомстве с сайтом, поэтому и говорю изучить правила. А Ваше [tag:нытьё] - просто требования, ибо **Вы** хотите. Тут хоть сообщество с репой решало и то - ещё не решили. Вы же приходите, обвиняете без доказательств (в чате) и требуете уважения к Вашим суждениям и требованиям.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36545855#36545855