# Программирование пояса бэтмена

Tags: обсуждение, 1-апреля

Решил взять у бэтмена пояс. Всё было хорошо работает, но когда я пытаюсь высунуть крюк, то пояс выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Runtime Error: Your weight does not match the weight specified in the system data.

Я бы у Брюса спросил, но он трубку не берёт. Кто знает, как исправить?

Схема пояса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: логи смотрел? Что там пишет? попробуй перезапустить пояс в надетом состоянии - должен подхватить твой вес

Comment: А отладчик не цепляется к нему?

Comment: Вроде бы есть функция updateWeight, обновляет данные с того, на кого пояс надет.

Comment: Попробуйте повторить эксперимент в [клетке Фарадея](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F), изменится ли сообщение?

Comment: @val подозреваю, что разработчики пояса её выпилили или заменили на бесполезную (совместимости ради). Интересно, не нарушает ли это лицензии библиотек, которые они туда вкрутили :Р

Comment: Для тех, кто выкладывает код картинками в аду предусмотрен отдельный котёл. Выложите исходники пояса, Ctrl+K или кнопка `{ }`на панели.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

К сожалению, разработчики оборудования для поясов слишком серьезно подошли к вопросам безопасности. По этому все важные настройки хранятся на трех независимых NAND микросхемах в зашифрованном виде. Шифровка/расшифровка данных производится аппаратными средствами, совмещенными с памятью.

Для изменения настроек веса крюка необходимо провести его рекалибровку следующим образом:

1. Подключите консоль к com-порту пояса.
2. К USB-порту подключите носитель системной цифровой подписи, с сертификатом, заверенным Batman inc.
3. Узнайте максимальную длину троса: `cat /proc/sys/dev/hook/max_length`
4. Возьмите воздушные шарики, наполненные гелием. Встаньте на весы, доведите свой вес, поддерживаемый шариками примерно до 10 кг.
5. Найдите два рядом стоящих здания, высотой превышающей максимальную длину троса
6. Перекиньте канат между этими зданиями.
7. Переведите пояс в режим калибровки крюка с помощью `echo 1 >/proc/sys/dev/hook/calibrate`. При этом крюк выйдет примерно на 2м
8. Подвесьте себя (с привязанными шариками) за крюк к канату между зданиями. *Внимание*: в процессе калибровки трос крюка будет несколько раз разматываться на всю длину, поэтому выбор высоты зданий очень важен.
9. Попросите какую нибудь знакомую свинью с ружьем постепенно отстреливать шарики со скоростью примерно 1 выстрел в минуту. Если опасаетесь за ее меткость можете дать холостые патроны и отцеплять шарики в такт выстрелам. Пояс при калибровке определяет по звуку выстрелов текущее расстояние до земли, так что просто увеличивать свой вес не выйдет.
10. Когда шарики закончатся просто отключите режим калибровки (`echo 0 >/proc/sys/dev/hook/calibrate`)

Примечания: следите за своим весом, в случае изменения на +-10 кг может потребоваться повторная рекалибровка. При спасении кого нибудь вместе с собой на крюке введите его вес в `/proc/sys/dev/hook/additional_weight` (Если вы в перчатках бэтмена и блютуз связь между компонентами одежды настроена, необходимо включить измеритель веса на запястье левой перчатки, подготовить пояс к приему информации о дополнительной нагрузке троекратным нажатием на третий от пряжки сегмент справа и приподнять спасаемого на 2 сек (15сек в моделях до 2000г) ).

Comment: *приподнять спасаемого на 15 сек* -- кошмар какой. Какого года этот аппарат?

Comment: @D-side Да, вы правы, в современных моделях время уменьшили до 2 сек. исправил

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :) Теперь можно по домам лазить спокойно

Comment: лазить по домам не получится, только между домами, при приближении к поверхности дома, крюк отстреливается. можно упасть. чтобы такого не происходило таки нужен шлем бетмена с автоматическим дальномером.

Answer (score 12):

Попробуй снять и снова надеть, мне помогало

Answer (score 10):

Ну так вот же решение данной проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень информативно )

Comment: @Yuri, я старалась, расписала все в подробностях))))

Answer (score 9):

Попробуй смёржить свой пояс с поясом железного человека, там этот баг уже пофиксили. А вообще - за архитектурой надо следить, ну кто же встраивает крюк в, прости господи, бляшку. Сами плодите трешкод, а потом жалуетесь)