# Быть ли вопросам-шуткам на День смеха (1 апреля) в 2018 году?

Tags: обсуждение

В 2017 пользователи StackOverflow впервые попробовали задать шуточные вопросы к празднованию Дня смеха (1 апреля).

Пример:
[Программирование пояса бэтмена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5069/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)

И не смотря на то, что под конец эта тема привела к казусу, в связи с незнанием, что делать с данными вопросами дальше, я считаю, что вышло достаточно тематично, интересно и "по домашнему".

*Поэтому образуется вопрос, быть ли вопросам-шуткам на День смеха (1 апреля) в 2018 году?*

<sup>С решением 2017-го года, все вопросы с меткой [1-апреля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f) или имеющие шуточный характер после Дня смеха будут перенесены на мету.</sup>

Comment: `под конец эта тема привела к казусу, в связи с незнанием, что делать с данными вопросами дальше` - не к казусу, а к вполне логичному завершению ибо никто разрешение не давал их задавать. Да, обсуждалась тема о 1 апреля, однако что именно делать - так и не решили. Поэтому все это было похоже на самопроизвол. Перенос всего этого с основного сайта - вполне логично.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну смотря что для Вас самопроизвол? Я считаю это праздничным духом :D

Comment: Произвол - это когда плевать на правила, установленные на конкретном ресурсе и делать то, что захочется и называть это праздничным духом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, та ладно. Ничего же плохого не случилось

Comment: Ну, скооперировшись, можно прийти к вам домой и накласть большие кучи фикалий на кровать и обеденный стол и называть это праздничным духом. А то, что у вас так не принято - что ничего же плохого не случилось.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, при том, казусом я называю не решение, а ситуацию до этого решения

Comment: Зачем было спрашивать? Раз с прошлого года все молчат, то делаем так же ;)

Comment: Кстати, в [ответе про пояс бэтмена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5070/208074) попали все картинки. Так что тот ответ стал абсолютно бесполезен.

Comment: @Arhad, там их и не было

Comment: @Yuri, а что тогда там делают нажимаемые изображения-пустышки?

Comment: @Arhad, Вам не кажется, что это вопрос не ко мне?

Comment: "Даже в самые тяжелые времена мы находили место для шютки, не правда ли, таварищ Жюков?" (с) Анекдот Я бы даже был не против (при строгом наличии тэга "юмор" для отсеивания очень серьезными людьми, и в разумном количестве, конечно) таких вопросов и не только 1 апреля. Кстати, а новогодние шляпы противников 1 апреля не раздражали? :)

Answer (score -4):

Не быть! Клоунаде, в таком виде, на таком серьёзном ресурсе как этот, не место.

Comment: Звучит как сарказм.

Comment: @alexolut "Просто принимайте регулярно филанизий, и будет всё хорошо."

Comment: Не было никаких проблем.