# Нет перевода последней строки на плашке о заблокированном вопросе

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, заблокированные-вопросы

В десятый раз решил перечитать [этот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5069/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) пост.

Под постом есть плашка, о том, что он заблокирован Nofate. Но последняя строчка "Read more about locked posts here." на этой плашке не переведена.

Comment: Скриншот надо. Я проблему не наблюдаю.

Comment: У меня тоже всё в порядке: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o9qs.png

Comment: Проблема была, я видел тоже. Видимо, при последней сборке починилось само :) @αλεχολυτ

Comment: @АндрейNOP или это была еще одна первоапрельская шуточка.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да, похоже все починилось. У меня тоже все нормально теперь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вчера новый перевод был утверждён и добавлен на сайт.

[image: текущее состояние перевода на сайте ru.traducir.win]

Comment: Ох уж эти ревьюверы ...